# Express JS and Multiple Mongodb Database Connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database

I am using Express JS at back-end and using mongoose package to connect to mongo database. In my project the requirement is i need to create separate database for each organization. Admin will add an organization and at that time i need to create a separate database for that organization using Schema written in models.

I did that using

```
var orgA = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/orgA');
var orgB = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/orgB');
```

I have used an JSON object to store the orgA and orgB. I have just mentioned it here to explain the things.

My question is how many connection i can create in my express js application and how it will effect the performance ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same troubles.

Comment: not exactly as of now